# Motion is saving images to home directory

Tags: home-directory

I was interested in setting up a home security network.  I installed **Motion** in Ubuntu 12.04 and it worked fine.  Then the next day I went to play around with it some more but the images are not being saved to /tmp/motion as the configuration file states, but to the home directory:

```
[1] File of type 1 saved to: ./01-20121126211634-12.jpg
```

Any idea if there is another setting that has more priority than the motion config file?

Comment: So I installed motion on a fresh computer and it saves the image files to the home folder by default.

Comment: I think I might have found the original problem.  When updating the config file, it is necessary to modify /etc/default/motion so that the daemon will run.  Otherwise, it will not refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default **Motion** use home directory with path `/home/motion` ...
So, to change this open your `terminal` and run it:

*for Gedit:*

```
gksudo gedit /etc/motion/motion.conf
```

*for vim:*

```
sudo vim /etc/motion/motion.conf
```

Find string started with: `target_dir`

Change value to your own some like a:

```
target_dir /tmp/motion
```

---

For using **Motion** through web interface you need to find or add this string in your config:

```
control_authentication USERNAME:PASSWORD
```

Then save the file, and add this USERNAME to the group motion:

```
adduser USERNAME motion
```

After this you can use Motion (if daemon is started) from web interface:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

---

From [**Precise Motion package manpages**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/motion.1.html):

> **-c**
>          Full    path    and    filename    of    config    file.
>          E.g. **/home/kurt/motion.conf**
>          Default is **/usr/local/etc** unless specified differently when building Motion.
>          Many RPMs and debian packages will most likely use **/etc** or **/etc/motion** as default.

Also I suggest you to refer with [**Motion Guides**](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/RunningMotionConfigFiles):

So if you can start your Motion with **-c** option but without **pathname** (check your simlink option):

```
motion -c      
// then Motion will use motion.conf
```

**OR** if you start Motion with point to your PATHNAME value:

```
motion -c <YOUR/PATHNAME>
// then Motion will use your custom config which will OVERRIDE the defaults.
```

Comment: In the configuration file at /etc/motion/motion.conf the default settings are already set to target_dir /tmp/motion.  When I changed the settings in /etc/default/motion to allow the daemon to run then it started to save the files in /tmp/motion.

Comment: updated ... enjoy your Motion :)

Comment: You should add that the daemon must be allowed to run from the config file at /etc/default/motion, otherwise it will save to the local home directory.

Comment: also look this dated Jun,2010: [Debian / Ubuntu problems](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/DebianUbuntu)
 ... and default for **Motion** daemon mode is OFF. Check option `daemon` in `motion.conf`. Daemon mode most often is in use on the server, with more strong and reliable configuration.

Comment: [Config Option target_dir](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/ConfigOptionTargetDir) ... if filename option already  contain relative syntax like a "./..." then perhaps it can override your preference in target_dir option. Also a ton of other options can affect this behavior. From [big Motion doc](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuideOneLargeDocument#Config_File_Options): Some configuration options are only used if Motion is built on a system that has the matching software libraries installed (MySQL, PostgreSQL and FFMPEG).